# How do I change default page background color in a word generated from R Markdown?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I need to produce several word documents from R Markdown. These word documents must have a blue background color.

I've already set the default page background color as blue by modifying Normal.dotm file and checked the option allowing it to appear when viewing documents in word.

When I open up a new document in word, it works, but when I create a word document serving as template to R Markdown (through `reference_docx` option in R Markdown yaml options) with a background color, the output word document does not seem to take into account the background color...

How can I achieve that ? I have hundreds of word documents to produce so I can't manually change the background color for all of them